# Could Power Shell be more harmfull than the command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

At an organisation/company/institute I know someone who can't use the command prompt on their work computers. The IT guys say this is for security reasons. If someone could use the command prompt, they have to much capability to cause harm. This person needed to use some basic commands but the IT guys still wouldn't help him/her. I tried for a few minutes and found out that the Power Shell works just fine. 
So is there a major security flaw at this organisation/company/institute, or is it normal that the command prompt is disabled but the Power Shell isn't?

Comment: If you are able to launch PowerShell, inside it, you can execute command prompt commands (possibly the IT team just blocks some commands in the user context and hide shortcuts to Command Prompt).

Normally, in this kind of situation IT Admin or Developer station with network restrictions and applied security purposes is proposed by enterprise IT. Also, it could be the same workstation but different privileged user. It look more like ServerFault question about workstation endpoints management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a flaw. PowerShell is much much stronger than CMD.

Using PowerShell you can do almost everything. You can load DLL's, you can add a domain controller and execute C# code, and do all of this without compiling anything.

The command line is a very limited tool that can only execute very specific cmdlets that were pre-defined and whenever you want to do something more clever with cmd you'll have to start another process.

Comment: But you can use the Power Shell, and not the command line. So this means that there is a major security flaw, right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: I might have understood the question wrong. I thought that you are asking why PowerShell is disabled and cmd enabled. 

If PowerShell is enabled there is no plain reason to disable cmd.